# Electron-builder mac os dmg file crashes at start

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder, dmg

I created a dmg mac file of my electron app with [electron builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder).

The creation process passes without any error.

The "installation" works, but if i try to start the app, it doesn't come up.

NOTE: Windows and linux builds work fine.

Used part of electron-builder mac config:

```
    "mac": {
        "icon": "dist/logo.png",
        "category": "test-app.app-category.developer-tools",
        "target": [
            "dmg"
        ]
    },
```

Stacktrace / error log:

```
Process:               appName [49598]
Path:                  /Applications/appName.app/Contents/MacOS/appName
Identifier:            ru.appName.app
Version:               1.4.0 (1.4.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           appName [49598]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-11-11 17:33:50.167 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G4015)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        8462CE6C-C934-0502-5981-B0725F5862FE

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4DFB8AC8-042E-4ADE-926D-5147B7CA609B

Time Awake Since Boot: 28000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       25000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        9  Chrome_IOThread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Thread 0:: CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d1ec7e0 0x10cb72000 + 6793184
1   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d1c7569 0x10cb72000 + 6641001
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e8614e4 0x10cb72000 + 30340324
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e83b4f7 0x10cb72000 + 30184695
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e8348c4 0x10cb72000 + 30156996
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e8d8f6c 0x10cb72000 + 30830444
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e83c23d 0x10cb72000 + 30188093
7   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e83c069 0x10cb72000 + 30187625
8   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e83fbbc 0x10cb72000 + 30202812
9   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e838107 0x10cb72000 + 30171399
10  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e837a81 0x10cb72000 + 30169729
11  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e91f57e 0x10cb72000 + 31118718
12  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e93de63 0x10cb72000 + 31243875
13  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e93cc27 0x10cb72000 + 31239207
14  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e93d13d 0x10cb72000 + 31240509
15  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d1a4dd1 0x10cb72000 + 6499793
16  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010cd945dc 0x10cb72000 + 2237916
17  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1e9279 0x10cb72000 + 40333945
18  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1ee17e 0x10cb72000 + 40354174
19  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1eda04 0x10cb72000 + 40352260
20  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1e63e3 0x10cb72000 + 40322019
21  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1e6c5a 0x10cb72000 + 40324186
22  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1fd02e 0x10cb72000 + 40415278
23  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eed2052 0x10cb72000 + 37093458
24  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eee1fe4 0x10cb72000 + 37158884
25  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eee257a 0x10cb72000 + 37160314
26  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3eb15 0x10cb72000 + 37538581
27  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ee7a69a 0x10cb72000 + 36734618
28  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3e45f 0x10cb72000 + 37536863
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd908f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fe4a30c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 108
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd73350 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd727cd __CFRunLoopRun + 1293
33  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd72033 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
34  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4f05cd96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
35  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4f05cb06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
36  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4f05c884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4d30ca73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4daa2e34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4d301885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
40  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3f2fc 0x10cb72000 + 37540604
41  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3de28 0x10cb72000 + 37535272
42  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eee2998 0x10cb72000 + 37161368
43  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeb6a17 0x10cb72000 + 36981271
44  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e6bd303 0x10cb72000 + 28619523
45  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e6be862 0x10cb72000 + 28624994
46  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e6ba5b6 0x10cb72000 + 28607926
47  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e578c82 0x10cb72000 + 27290754
48  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e57889e 0x10cb72000 + 27289758
49  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000011068c339 0x10cb72000 + 61973305
50  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d721f84 0x10cb72000 + 12255108
51  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010cb74b54 AtomMain + 84
52  ru.appName.app                  0x000000010c64a9e0 main + 240 (atom_main.cc:233)
53  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff77ca8015 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df928a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df928a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df928a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df928a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc020e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df928a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc020e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:: ThreadPoolServiceThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df9c02 kevent64 + 10
1   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3658a 0x10cb72000 + 37504394
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef363f6 0x10cb72000 + 37503990
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eee2998 0x10cb72000 + 37161368
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeb6a17 0x10cb72000 + 36981271
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eee5a97 0x10cb72000 + 37173911
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eef1f46 0x10cb72000 + 37224262
7   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77dee724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eecf045 0x10cb72000 + 37081157
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeed8dd 0x10cb72000 + 37206237
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedf60 0x10cb72000 + 37207904
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedba4 0x10cb72000 + 37206948
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77dee724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eecf045 0x10cb72000 + 37081157
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeed8dd 0x10cb72000 + 37206237
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedf60 0x10cb72000 + 37207904
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedb14 0x10cb72000 + 37206804
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9 Crashed:: Chrome_IOThread
0   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ee8bc66 0x10cb72000 + 36805734
1   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e873352 0x10cb72000 + 30413650
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e875251 0x10cb72000 + 30421585
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e876ca5 0x10cb72000 + 30428325
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e6b61a0 0x10cb72000 + 28590496
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f54281a 0x10cb72000 + 43845658
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1ea198 0x10cb72000 + 40337816
7   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f5465d7 0x10cb72000 + 43861463
8   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f54775d 0x10cb72000 + 43865949
9   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1e5c46 0x10cb72000 + 40320070
10  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1fd02e 0x10cb72000 + 40415278
11  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1fd308 0x10cb72000 + 40416008
12  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010f1fc7a3 0x10cb72000 + 40413091
13  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d6706d9 0x10cb72000 + 11527897
14  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d66fffc 0x10cb72000 + 11526140
15  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d66c83d 0x10cb72000 + 11511869
16  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d66382e 0x10cb72000 + 11474990
17  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010d6741ae 0x10cb72000 + 11542958
18  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef37513 0x10cb72000 + 37508371
19  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef365d8 0x10cb72000 + 37504472
20  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef363f6 0x10cb72000 + 37503990
21  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eee2998 0x10cb72000 + 37161368
22  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeb6a17 0x10cb72000 + 36981271
23  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010e6c4364 0x10cb72000 + 28648292
24  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eef1f46 0x10cb72000 + 37224262
25  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df9bea kevent + 10
1   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000011257bd0a 0x10cb72000 + 94412042
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000011256b6b1 uv_run + 497
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001124e7616 0x10cb72000 + 93804054
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df8a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc1589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000112577089 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001124e7728 0x10cb72000 + 93804328
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001124e539b 0x10cb72000 + 93795227
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df8a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc1589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000112577089 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001124e7728 0x10cb72000 + 93804328
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001124e539b 0x10cb72000 + 93795227
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df8a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc1589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000112577089 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001124e7728 0x10cb72000 + 93804328
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001124e539b 0x10cb72000 + 93795227
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def246 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001125775f0 uv_sem_wait + 16
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000112532472 0x10cb72000 + 94110834
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:: NetworkConfigWatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77dee724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd73665 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd729b7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd72033 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff51e6fe76 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3f001 0x10cb72000 + 37539841
7   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3de28 0x10cb72000 + 37535272
8   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eee2998 0x10cb72000 + 37161368
9   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeb6a17 0x10cb72000 + 36981271
10  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eef1f46 0x10cb72000 + 37224262
11  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:: CrShutdownDetector
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77dfa142 read + 10
1   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010cc21abf 0x10cb72000 + 719551
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: NetworkConfigWatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77dee724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd73665 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd729b7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4fd72033 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff51e6fe76 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3f001 0x10cb72000 + 37539841
7   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef3de28 0x10cb72000 + 37535272
8   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eee2998 0x10cb72000 + 37161368
9   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeb6a17 0x10cb72000 + 36981271
10  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eef1f46 0x10cb72000 + 37224262
11  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77dee724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eecf045 0x10cb72000 + 37081157
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeed8dd 0x10cb72000 + 37206237
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedf60 0x10cb72000 + 37207904
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedba4 0x10cb72000 + 37206948
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 19:: CompositorTileWorker1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df8a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc1589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef2d325 0x10cb72000 + 37466917
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000110212f9d 0x10cb72000 + 57282461
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 20:: ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77dee724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eecf045 0x10cb72000 + 37081157
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeed8dd 0x10cb72000 + 37206237
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedf60 0x10cb72000 + 37207904
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedba4 0x10cb72000 + 37206948
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 21:: ThreadPoolSingleThreadForegroundBlocking0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77dee724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eecf045 0x10cb72000 + 37081157
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeed8dd 0x10cb72000 + 37206237
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedf60 0x10cb72000 + 37207904
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010eeedc04 0x10cb72000 + 37207044
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ef38307 0x10cb72000 + 37511943
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77def246 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001125775f0 uv_sem_wait + 16
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ccae8f8 0x10cb72000 + 1296632
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff77df8a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc1589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   com.apple.GeForceMTLDriver      0x00007fff4b690cc2 0x7fff4b530000 + 1445058
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc0661 _pthread_body + 340
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fc050d _pthread_start + 377
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff77fbfbf9 thread_start + 13




Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3

...

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 18489
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=493.1M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=493.1M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=392.8M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=392.8M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               384K        3 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
CG backing stores                  776K        5 
CG image                            20K        3 
CoreAnimation                       24K        4 
CoreImage                            8K        3 
CoreServices                      6656K        2 
CoreUI image data                  520K        5 
CoreUI image file                  180K        4 
Foundation                          28K        3 
IOKit                             15.5M        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                           147.8M       36 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       12 
Mach message                        16K        3 
Memory Tag 242                      12K        2 
Memory Tag 255                   157.3M      139 
PROTECTED_MEMORY                     4K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       36 
Stack                            204.3M       36 
VM_ALLOCATE                        256K       14 
__DATA                            35.7M      290 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        2 
__LINKEDIT                       197.4M       10 
__TEXT                           295.7M      293 
__UNICODE                          560K        2 
mapped file                       61.0M       21 
shared memory                      756K       10 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.2G      918 

Model: iMac14,2, BootROM 133.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 3,2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.15f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341384758334D314131363030433131
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x111), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.31.1a9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f11, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD WD10EZES-40UFAA0, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 23.10
```

Electron-builder version 22.1.0

Comment: Facing similar issue, any luck? is there a way to debug the build?